# How to transfer bitcoin bought online to my desktop wallet?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, electrum, coinbase.com

Based on popular recommendations, I have started with Electrum as my Ubuntu desktop wallet and Coinbase as the way to buy bitcoin online.

However, it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to transfer bitcoins from Coinbase to Electrum (not without using a paper wallet).

Is this correct? If I want to conveniently buy bitcoins only, but want to securely store them on my own offline hard drive, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Coinbase allows you to send all your bitcoins to your local Electrum wallet. I think it's in the "wallet" tab on your accounts page.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily send your bitcoins from Coinbase to Electrum.

Once logged into Coinbase click on the Send / Request button on your left hand menu. A form will pop up asking for an email address or bitcoin address.

What you want to do is enter in one of your bitcoin addresses from Electrum. Open up Electrum and click on the tab labeled "Receive". You can pick any address that is listed there under Main Account > Receiving.  Pick one, copy it and paste it in the Coinbase form that asks for an email address or bitcoin address.

From there just complete the form and hit send. Your funds will now be transferred to the address on your Electrum wallet. Be sure to [back up your wallet](http://bitzuma.com/posts/a-beginners-guide-to-the-electrum-bitcoin-wallet/#make-a-backup) and seed. If your computer crashes/breaks and you don't have a back up YOU WILL LOSE ALL OF YOUR COINS.

Answer (score 3):

I did this today and the procedure is currently (2017-10-31) as follows (Electrum 2.9.3):

Prepare Electrum to receive
* Make sure Electrum is online (green icon bottom right)
* Click 'Receive' and copy the receiving address to your clipboard (there's a little blue icon for that at the right)

Go to Coinbase to send
* Click on 'Accounts'
* At the bottom of the BTC Wallet section, click 'Send'
* Paste the address you copied from Electrum
* Specify the amount of BTC you want to send, click Continue
* In the next window, enter the confirmation code which Coinbase sends by SMS, and click Confirm

Coinbase will now show a window confirming the transaction.
Go back to Electrum and wait until it confirms there the BTC has been arrived. You can check that under the tab 'Addresses'. Note: Electrum shows mBTC.
Coinbase also provides a link to BlockCypher where you follow the transaction.

Comment: Also note that it takes time to process the transaction, in my case it took about two hours to receive the confirmation.